# Jquery endless loop not focusing in proper field

Tags: php, html, jquery, laravel

I'm trying to read barcode reader input, then find the product from a table.

If a product is available jQuery works fine, but when the product is not in the table then the program should focus on the barcode input field, the problem is it gets into an endless loop.

**This is the important part of the code**

```
$('#barcode').focusout(function() {
  var barcode = $(this).val();
  $.ajax({
    type: "get",
    url: "{{url('productdetails')}}?barcode=" + barcode,
    success: function(res) {
      if (res) {

        /*   process steps  */

        $("#barcode").val("");
        setTimeout(function() {
          $("input#barcode").focus();
        }, 100);

      } else {
        alert('no data found');
        $("#barcode").val("");
        setTimeout(function() {
          $("#barcode").focus();
        }, 100);

      }
    },
    error: function() {
      alert('Error Method: no data found');

    },
  });
  alert('no Action');
  $("#barcode").val("");
  $("#barcode").focus();
});
```

> **Note**: I am not familiar with the proper formatting of the question
> posting please ignore if you find unfit it as the question.

Comment: Hint: A normal barcode scanner will scan the barcode and input it into the input box PLUS a carriage return. Hence your ajax should only be triggered when a carriage return is detected in the input box- say using  **onkeypress**. (After the ajax return then just put the cursor back to the input box without triggering any ajax). For the db part since you did not post any PHP code there is no way to further comment

Comment: Thanks for the response and hint.  I trigger to process the given method after scanning and focus out.  if product found all is well cursor position come to barcode input field but in other scenarios cursor remain out and the process loops in the above method.  Any hint how can i position cursor in barcode input field.